# Set the last td value on basis of his data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, html-table

I am working on one table that is created using datatables. Now I want to set last td value using jquery. I tried different codes but no luck like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

       $('#productsTable tr').each(function() {
           alert($(this).closest('tr').children('td.two').text());
           // alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(11)').text());
       });
    });
</script>
```

I didn't get the proper value of last td. My table html is:

```
<table class="display table table-bordered table-striped dataTable" id="productsTable" aria-describedby="productsTable_info">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 45.777777671814px;">Date</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Auction: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 75.777777671814px;">Auction</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Bid no: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 62.777777671814px;">Bid no</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 55.777777671814px;">Name</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Chassis No: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 107.777777671814px;">Chassis No</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Year: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 46.777777671814px;">Year</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Color: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 53.777777671814px;">Color</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Mileage: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 75.777777671814px;">Mileage</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Score: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 58.777777671814px;">Score</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Bid: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 35.777777671814px;">Bid</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="End Price: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 95.777777671814px;">End Price</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Result" style="width: 63.777777671814px;">Result</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" sorting_1">2015-05-08</td>
            <td class="">SAA Sapporo</td>
            <td class="">3005</td>
            <td class="">FIT SHUTTLE</td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class="">2012</td>
            <td class="">WHITE</td>
            <td class="">23</td>
            <td class="">4.5</td>
            <td class="">0</td>
            <td class="">0</td>
            <td class="">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class=" sorting_1">2015-05-08</td>
            <td class="">SAA Sapporo</td>
            <td class="">55097</td>
            <td class="">PIXIS EPOCH</td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class="">2012</td>
            <td class="">.....</td>
            <td class="">8</td>
            <td class="">4.5</td>
            <td class="">0</td>
            <td class="">0</td>
            <td class="">0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to set the result values like if `1` then winner and `2` then losre etc., but issue is I am not getting the value of last td. What I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `:last` selector along with td elements object:

```
$('#productsTable tr:has(td)').each(function() {
 alert($(this).find('td:last').text());
});
```

This will alert the text of each last td element in trs.

Comment: can you reproduce that in fiddle??

Comment: `:last-child` is what you want. `.last()` is a jQuery function

Comment: i think databtable are creating using js may be that effects ? what you suggest

Comment: see the demo http://jsfiddle.net/vrw6t2md/. also you should call above code when data is rendered in datatable,

Comment: when i change to `$('#productsTable tr:has(td)')` i didnt get any alert or error ?

Comment: well that means data is not loaded in table. how are you loading the data??

Comment: I am getting data from php and assign that to datatables like `$this->prepare_datatable_ajax($data)`.And it last datatables creates table for that data.

Comment: do it have success function?? when we know that data is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using data tables, it will be better to use the [datatables api](https://www.datatables.net/reference/api/)

```
$('#productsTable tbody tr td:last-child').each(function () {
    var cell = table.cell(this),
        data = cell.data();
    if (data == 1) {
        cell.data('Winner');
    } else if (data == 0) {
        cell.data('Lost');
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/o8gs83jj/)

Comment: thanks but when i run your code on my side its doing nothing.i put alert on data values but no alert.i think its not goes inside the code.

Comment: i write code like this : `$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#productsTable').DataTable();
   $('#productsTable tbody tr td:last-child').each(function () {
    var cell = table.cell(this),
        data = cell.data();
        alert(data);
    if (data == 1) {
        cell.data('Winner');
    } else if (data == 0) {
        cell.data('Lost');
    }
})
    });`

Comment: Sorry the first question should have been how is the data loaded to the table.... is it done dynamically.... or do you have a normal table with data which is then converted to datatables